# javascript: manually invoking a self-invoked function

Tags: javascript

I have something similar to the code below:

```
var msg="first call";
(function test(msg)
    {
        console.log("inside self call");
    }
)();

msg="second call";
console.log("before inline call");
test(msg);
console.log("after inline call");
```

Where I need to call a function (that is self-invoked at the beginning of the code).

It seems to me that I can not call a self-invoked function. But I am not sure as this is the first time I face such situation. This is the output I'm getting in the console:

```
inside self call
before inline call
ReferenceError: test is not defined
```

Is there a way other than repeating the function code with another name?

Comment: Why don't you split declaration and first invokation?

Comment: In [*old versions of IE*](https://kangax.github.io/nfe/#jscript-bugs), function expressions with a name became global functions, so actually it will work in some (faulty) browsers. ;-)

Comment: Not using an IIFE in the first place would be the most sensible approach. Use a function declaration, then call that function. Later: call it again.

Answer (score 0):

The <s>self invoking function</s> expression has its own scope
This article describe and gives a work around:
https://christierney.com/2012/09/05/accessing-javascript-methods-from-outside-its-self-invoking-function-wrapper/

> Let’s say you have a method you want to be globally accessible, but
>   want a self-invoking function around it to make sure it’s jQuery $
>   alias safe.
>
> In this example, the following code is in global.js:
>
> ```
> (function( $ ) {
>    function showLoader( cfg ) {
>       if( cfg == 'show') {
>          $( '.loader' ).show();
>       } else //more code...
>    }
> })(jQuery);
> ```
>
> In this example, the following code is in myPage.js:
>
> ```
> (function($) {
>    showLoader( 'show' );
> })(jQuery);
> ```
>
> You will find that myPage.js cannot access the showLoader() method
>   even though global.js was called first in the HTML page.
>
> The fix for this is to push the showLoader() method out to the window
>   (global) scope:
>
> ```
> (function( $ ) {
>    window.showLoader = function( cfg ) {
>       if( cfg == 'show') {
>          $( '.loader' ).show();
>       } else //more code...
>    }
> })(jQuery);
> ```
>
> By assigning the function to the window scope it is now globally
>   accessible. Just remember that it is now no longer protected by the
>   closure but it still has access to the jQuery $ alias.

Comment: it's not the self invoking function has an own scope, rather the expresssion has an own scope. you could use a named self invoking function and use it as a recusion inside, with the given name. the name exists only in the expression's scope.

Comment: @NinaScholz Yes definitely you are right, thanks, I will update my answer